# Unable to stop initial sorting using datatables

Tags: jquery, mysql, sorting, datatables

I am using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) 1.10.7.

My original question referenced here [Question on datatables forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28221/unable-to-stop-initial-sorting#latest)

I want to disable the initial sort that datatables does automatically.

Datatables refuses to listen to

```
"aaSorting": []
```

OR

```
"aaSorting": [[0,'desc'],[1,'desc']]
```

It sorts by the first column in the table in ASC order. The only way to stop this is to use

```
"bSort": false
```

however that removes all sorting functionality on my table.

My table works 100% for everything else except sorting. Filtering, searching, paging etc works 100%. When I set

```
"bSort" : true
```

or, when I leave it out, as I believe the default is true, I get the following error in a alert message:

"error":"An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY column1 ASC LIMIT 0, 10' at line 4"

I have tried with and without aaSorting, with and without bSort and mixing them together in various ways.

Any help ?

PS, here is my table definitions:

```
oTable = $('#table_demo').DataTable(
{
    "bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": [[0,'desc'],[1,'desc']],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "view_demo_remote.php",
        "data":
        {
            "field1": "".$_SESSION['field1']."",
            "field2": "".$_SESSION['field2']."",
            "field3": "".$_SESSION['field3'].""
        }
    },
    "columns":[
        { "bSortable": true, "data": "col1" },
        { "bSortable": true, "data": "col2" },
        { "bSortable": true, "data": "col3" },
        { "bSortable": false, "data": "col4" },
        { "bSortable": false, "data": "col5" },
        { "bSortable": false, "data": "col6" }
    ],
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex )
    {
        $(nRow).attr("attrname",aData["col1"]);
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings )
    {

    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried using this from the latest api , but with no success:

```
"order": []
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my view_demo_remote.php for the server side processing:

```
<?php
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */

    session_start();

        $table = 'table_demo';

        $primaryKey = 'id';

        $field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["field1"]);
        $field2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["field2"]);
        $field3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["field3"]);


    $columns = array(
            array(
                'db' => 'id',
                'dt' => 'DT_RowId',
                'formatter' => function( $d, $row )
                {
                    return $d;
                }
            ),
            array( 'db' => 'name',   'dt' => 'col1' ),
            array( 'db' => 'surname',   'dt' => 'col2' ),
            array( 'db' => 'title',   'dt' => 'col3' ),
            array( 'db' => 'date',   'dt' => 'col4' ),
            array( 'db' => 'telephone',   'dt' => 'col5' ),
            array( 'db' => 'email',   'dt' => 'col6' )
            );


        $sql_details = array(
                'user' => DBUSER,
                'pass' => DBUSERPASS,
                'db'   => DBNAME,
                'host' => DBHOST
        );


        require( 'libraries/DataTables-1.10.7/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );


        echo json_encode(SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, "","name <>'' ORDER BY id DESC, datecreated DESC"));
```

Comment: which version of datatable are you using ? to use `"aaSorting": []` version must be 1.5 or greater. see [this](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5/how-to-prevent-initial-sorting)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar as stated on the very first line of my post, I am using 1.10.7. Which means in fact that I should be using order instead of aasorting, however, both does not work.

Comment: @Janpan: You datatable code seems perfect. I think the issue is with your view_demo_remote.php file. Can you add your php code.

Comment: @AmarKamthe sure thing, will add it now.

Comment: Just try removing the last two parameters from SSP::complex function and check whether the datatable works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [order](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) to specify that no initial ordering should occur is perfectly fine, see the example below:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": []
} );
```

There is an error in your PHP code in call to `SSP::complex`. The functions expects the following arguments

```
static function complex ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )
```

but you're specifying `"name <>'' ORDER BY id DESC, datecreated DESC"` for `$whereAll` argument.

This may work if sorting is disabled, but when it's not and another column is sorted, `SSP` class will use two `ORDER` clauses (one from `$whereAll` argument and another based on the column being sorted) resulting in SQL error.

Replace `"name <>'' ORDER BY id DESC, datecreated DESC"` with `"name <>''"` to correct this issue.

Comment: Thx, that did the trick ! I suspected that might be part of the problem. I was a bit unsure on how to order when using server side and I just made it part of the where clause and it worked, but obviously it was not written to be used in that way. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the order method instead?

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Sort by column 1 and then re-draw
table
    .order( [] )
    .draw();
```

Comment: Yes I have, same error occurs :( I beleive the error actually happens before that.

Comment: What it looks like is that MySql is complaining because of the formmated column name <code>column1</code>, You should handle it to strip those tags before doing the query

Comment: Sorry, thats just the formatting applied as I copied it out of a response string. the actual message displays as plain text. I will fix it in the original post to avoid confusion.